# Which one is more efficient the method std::basic_string::append or the operator '+'?

Tags: c++11, std, stdstring

Which one is more efficient in avoiding unnecessary copy the `append` method or the `Operator +` in **C++11**?

```
std::string salute = "Hello";
std::string message = salute.append("Namaste");
```

OR

```
std::string salute = "Hello";
std::string message = salute + "Namaste";
```

`Operator +` allocates a new buffer but it also has R-value reference constructor which avoids the copy of the rvalue. On the contrary `append` doesn't allocate new buffer(Right?) but doesn't have any overloaded function with R-value reference parameter.

Comment: Measure, always measure. Do this operation a million times in a loop that you measure the time for, and divide the elapsed time to get an average.

Comment: Right! But how does that help you understand the underlying concepts?

Comment: Do you mean you want implementation-specific information about these operations? That's really a little to broad, especially considering that you don't tell us what compiler, standard library and versions of them you're using. But to give some detail, even the `append` call could lead to memory allocations, if the string object doesn't have enough capacity for the new concatenated string.

Comment: the waters get even muddier when you add small-string-optimization to the mix :)

Comment: Also note that all append-type function ([`operator+`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B), [`operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) and [`append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append)) have overloads that take a character pointer, which will be used in your example.

Answer (score 4):

Both `operator+` and `std::basic_string::append` have overloads that avoid unnecessary copies of string literals - w.r.t. to unnecessary temporaries/copies you won't see any runtime performance difference.

Besides, these two options aren't functionally equivalent. `std::basic_string::append` mutates the object, whereas `operator+` does not. In your first example, this leads to `salute` being "HelloNamaste" while it is "Hello" in the second example. I think this is the intended use case of `append` (it returns a reference, not a new object):

```
std::string salute = "Hello";
salute.append("abc").append("def");
```

while the creation of a new object is better done with `operator+`. As the intention of both functions differs, I am not sure whether it's very meaningful to compare their runtime performance characteristics.

As a last note, `operator+` can be implemented in terms of `append`, which is the case in the `<string>` header from libcxx:

> ```
> template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
> inline
> basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>
> operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs, const _CharT* __rhs)
> {
>     basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator> __r(__lhs.get_allocator());
>     typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::size_type __lhs_sz = __lhs.size();
>     typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::size_type __rhs_sz = _Traits::length(__rhs);
>     __r.__init(__lhs.data(), __lhs_sz, __lhs_sz + __rhs_sz);
>     __r.append(__rhs, __rhs_sz);
>     return __r;
> }
> ```